# How to create an article with "show on demand" part of the text of the article?

Tags: nodes

What I am trying to do is like in the picture.
So I would have an article of same text of multiple language. When I click on the Flag/text link on top of the article, it should show particular part of the text of that language selected. All other texts should be hidden. Is that something easily achievable? Can anyone suggest how to go with it please?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your use case, there is no module for it. You will need to use custom jQuery

#### [SEE MY DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/wwo8ghno/32/)

For Example:

#### HTML

```
<span class="french-flag">
<img src="http://icons.iconseeker.com/png/128/rounded-world-flags/france-flag-2.png"/>
</span>
<span class="english-flag">
<img src="http://icons.iconseeker.com/png/128/rounded-world-flags/us-pacific-island-wildlife-refuges.png"/>
</span>

<br>

<div class="french-text">
Merci
</div>

<div class="english-text">
Thank you
</div>
```

#### jQuery

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
 $('.french-flag, .english-flag').css("cursor", "pointer");
 $('.french-text, .english-text').hide();

$('.french-flag').click(function() {
  $('.french-text').show();
  $('.english-text').hide();
});

$('.english-flag').click(function() {
  $('.english-text').show();
  $('.french-text').hide();
});

});
```

**but in drupal you need to wrap your js code inside**

```
(function ($) {
   // code goes here
})(jQuery);
```

**So your Drupal JS code (example.js) needs to be**

```
(function ($) {
     $( document ).ready(function() {
     $('.french-flag, .english-flag').css("cursor", "pointer");
     $('.french-text, .english-text').hide();

    $('.french-flag').click(function() {
      $('.french-text').show();
      $('.english-text').hide();
    });

    $('.english-flag').click(function() {
      $('.english-text').show();
      $('.french-text').hide();
    });

    });
})(jQuery);
```

To add/load your jQuery/java script to drupal, there are various methods, see/read **[Working with JavaScript and jQuery](https://www.drupal.org/node/171213)**

Comment: Excellent!!! Many thanks. Is there a way to load the english by default?

Comment: change this line `$('.french-text, .english-text').hide();` to `$('.french-text').hide();` **[revised demo](https://jsfiddle.net/wwo8ghno/35/)**

Comment: I will be creating many articles like this. is there a automated process where I can select language and text, and articles get populated, regardless number of languages i would like to add?? Otherwise I need to keep modify the code for each language, and they may not always be same.

Comment: you just need to create one .js file that has all the possible languages. I only did 2, so you just keep adding more. Then when you post your articles, as long as your flags and text fields have the corresponding div class, this will work.

Comment: One last question, I have managed to add a new .js to my theme and its working perfectly, except the images are appearing in huge sizes, although they are like 40x40 px. They are also appearing one after another vertically and not side by side!! how can I fix this please?

Comment: to make them appear side by side you can either use a `<span>` or if you're using a `<div>` then you need to add to your css file `.french-flag { float: left; }` If images are appearing in huge sizes, check your css, there might be a code that is causing them to enlarge OR use css again `.french-flag img { width: 40px; height: 40px; }`